# Foreground Service Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-notifications, foreground-service

I want to track a value when the app is closed and not visible to the user and when the value changes it gets a notification
I tried Foreground Service but there is a notification in the status bar and it can't be deleted
Also, when the application is closed and I want to access it again, the response is weak and the application stops.
Android Studio and the Java programming language
Thank you

Comment: Have you considered running a [background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) then?

Comment: I tried Foreground Service, but it has problems such as after entering the application after a period of time, it has a weak response to the application